# Retrieve react context within a <custom-web-component />?

Tags: reactjs, web-component, react-context

I have a defined `<custom-web-component />` that might appear anywhere in a DOM at runtime in a react-based application.  The `<custom-web-component />`'s `connectedCallback()` tells a `<Manager />` react component elsewhere to `createPortal(<Foo />, this)`, injecting more react content inside the placement of the `<custom-web-component />`.

The injected content seems to have access to React Context that is available to `<Manager />` wherever it is mounted in the react tree.  This works for me just fine for most React Contexts because I can just ensure that `<Manager />` inside the necessary context providers too.

My trouble is that react-router-dom's purpose is more sensitive to the placement in the react tree.  With the `<Manager />` near the root of the react tree, `<Foo />` doesn't know what  `"/route/segments/*"` have been matched already for nested routing compared to if `<Foo />` were just mounted there as a typical child element.  `<Foo />`'s route paths need to be basically root-relative and this is undesirable.

I want to restore more intuitive Routing support by stealing context from the parent of `<custom-web-component />` somehow and [restoring the router context](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7545#issuecomment-895581910) with `<UNSAFE_RouteContext.Provider value={parentContext } />` wrapping `<Foo />` inside the portal.

But how to get `parentContext`?  Again, the `<custom-web-component />` might get placed anywhere (by non-react code) and even inside other such portals.  I can't do `parentContext = React.useContext(UNSAFE_RouteContext)` inside the web-component because it's not a react functional component.

My best idea is to 1) somehow locate the instance of `<custom-web-component />` in the react tree and then 2) somehow extract the router context from it (or its parent?).  Is there a way to do these two steps?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is complex, especially concerning react-router-dom's context sensitivity. Since `<custom-web-component />` is not a React functional component, typical React methods like `useContext` won't work.

One way to solve this could be to pass the router context as a prop to `<Manager />`, which in turn passes it to `<Foo />` when creating the portal. You can capture the router context at the point where `<custom-web-component />` is instantiated, assuming it's within a React functional component at that point, and then forward it to `<Manager />`.

Another way and less conventional way is to traverse the DOM up from the `<custom-web-component />` to find the nearest parent with the router context, then pass that back to `<Manager />`. This is more hacky and could be less reliable.

Given the constraints, I don't think there is a perfect solution, but these approaches might give you a way to manually pass along the needed context.

Comment: "Another way and less conventional way is to traverse the DOM up from the <custom-web-component /> to find the nearest parent."    How, please?